# Run a python script based on schedule time using croniter

Tags: python, cron

I have a function to do some work. The code should repeat based on schedule. I used Croniter module. the schedule should be in cron type syntax. It works with every minutes. But it doesn't work with seconds. I added seconds at last in schedule but it says croniter syntax is not acceptable. How do I add seconds in syntax to make it work for seconds also? 
Here is my code.

```
import yaml
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

def fun():
    for i in items:
        print (i)
def roundDownTime(dt=None, dateDelta=timedelta(minutes=1)):
    roundTo = dateDelta.total_seconds()
    if dt == None : dt = datetime.now()
    seconds = (dt - dt.min).seconds
    rounding = (seconds+roundTo/2) // roundTo * roundTo
    return dt + timedelta(0,rounding-seconds,-dt.microsecond)
def getNextCronRunTime(schedule):
    return croniter(schedule, datetime.now()).get_next(datetime)
def sleepTillTopOfNextMinute():
    t = datetime.utcnow()
    sleeptime = 60 - (t.second + t.microsecond/1000000.0)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)

items =[2,4,6,7]
schedule =  "*/1 * 7 2 * "
nextRunTime = getNextCronRunTime(schedule)
while True:
     roundedDownTime = roundDownTime()
     if (roundedDownTime == nextRunTime):
         fun()
         nextRunTime = getNextCronRunTime(schedule)
     elif (roundedDownTime > nextRunTime):
         # We missed an execution. Error. Re initialize.
         nextRunTime = getNextCronRunTime(schedule)
     sleepTillTopOfNextMinute()
```

Comment: When you define a cron job, the least you can go up to is minutes:
* * * * * (minute, hour, day of the month, month, day of the week)
You can refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for more details

Comment: is there any other way to add seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know of any other software that works like cron. Maybe try a google search?

Comment: have you tried `APScheduler`

Comment: Or maybe try ‘schedule’: https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/README.rst